# how to move, rotate and scale multiple objects in edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I can only go into edit mode on one object at a time in as far as i can figure out.

So if i have 10 objects, is there a way to move, rotate or scale all 10 of them together in edit mode?

I don't want to do it in object mode as that does nothing to the meshes and when i export fbx, all object mode stuff is gone.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your objects in OBJECT MODE, then apply the transformation to the mesh (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: that works great but i've noticed a side effect. when i export to .fbx then import into unity game engine, i can't rotate in Z anymore. rotate in X and Y is fine, but Z rotation moves X. this only started happeneing after i did the ctrl-A. its probably more of a unity question but can anyone think why this is happeneing? thanks

Comment: I've just tried (blender 2.78 + unity 5.5) and the objects rotate in X,Y and Z correctly. As you say, maybe it's a unity setting or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

When scaling make sure you don't have all axes locked for scaling. Otherwise you won't even see the gizmo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In blender 2.8 you can select multiple objects and go into edit mode.

If the meshes not rotating in object mode, may be manipulate centers icon is on, make sure it is disabled.

[image]